# Why my mathematical if statement fails?

Tags: php

I am writing simple drop formula for player A vs. B fights - level difference determinates drop rate. My issue here is that instead of `0: > 10 ||| 1 vs. 1 = 10%` it gives `0: > 10 ||| 1 vs. 1 = 0%` - why?

PhpFiddle: http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/n1q-dw7

```
<?php

# lets simulate high level player A attacks low level player B
for ($A = 1; $A <= 100; $A++) {
    $B = 1;
    calculateMoneyDrop($A,$B);
}

# lets simulate low level player A attacks high level player B
for ($B = 1; $B <= 100; $B++) {
    $A = 1;
    calculateMoneyDrop($A,$B);
}

function calculateMoneyDrop($A,$B) {
    $X = $A - $B;
    echo '<strong>', $X, '</strong>: ';

    switch ($X) {
        case $X > 10:
            echo "> 10 ||| ";
            $X = 10;
            break;
        case $X < -90:
            echo "< -90 ||| ";
            $X = -90;
            break;
    }

    $dropRate = 10 - $X;
    echo $A, ' vs. ', $B, ' = ', $dropRate, '%<br>';

}
```

Comment: Why using `switch` instead of `if` ?

Comment: Your expected result should be 0  1 vs. 1 = 10%,  it shouldn't execute either of your case statements, but as you only have two conditions and no default, why not use an if and see if that returns the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your `$X > 10` case you set `$X = 10` and later calculate `$dropRate` as `10 - $X`, which is `10 - 10`, which is `0`.

Either the `$dropRate` should be `$X` if the desired outcome is `10`. It also strikes me funny that the output says `$X == 0` first, but then enters the switch case `$X > 10`... Are you sure that you're showing us all the code?

Also I don't think it's good practice to use the `switch` case like that. This is a typical candidate for an `if` block.

Comment: Go and test it in fiddle if you dont belive

Comment: The reason for entering the switch case for `$X > 10` is explained by Karoly Horvath in his answer. `$X` is `0` and `0` equals `false` in PHP and `$X > 10` (which is `0 > 10`) also equals `false`, so the case matches (the condition `$X > 10` is `false` and `$X` is also "`false`"), so this case is entered. Long story short: Use `if` clauses and you're fine.

Comment: Just seen this explanation.  switch (true) also resolves the problem

Comment: That would be about the worst thing to do, don't you think? The switch statement has its purpose in PHP, but this situation just isn't the situation to use it.

Answer (score 4):

It's simply how switch-case works. It checks whether `$X` equals to the value you list in `case`. Since that value is a boolean (result of a comparison is a boolean!), and PHP has a crazy way to [compare different types](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (in this case `int` and `bool`), that block of case will actually be executed.

Use `if` statements, or use `min` and `max`.

Comment: That is a really great explanation I didn't even consider! That explains at least why it enters the `$X > 10` case...

Answer (score 1):

If you change your switch to

```
 switch (true) {
```

the original code runs correctly.

Perhaps someone with better php than me can explain why!

http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/6pg-nwc

Answer (score 0):

Your switch block does the same as:

```
if(($X > 10)==$X){
        echo "> 10 ||| ";
        $X = 10;
}
else if(($X < -90)==$X){
        echo "< -90 ||| ";
        $X = -90;
}
```

It compares whatever you have at "case" to whatever you have in the switches parentheses.
Switch is used only for "equals" comparisons.
so, to make it work, use:

```
if($X > 10){
        echo "> 10 ||| ";
        $X = 10;
}
else if($X < -90){
        echo "< -90 ||| ";
        $X = -90;
}
```